# Azure functions TypeScript publish give error Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.2.8.0, Culture=neutral

Tags: node.js, typescript, azure-functions

I have created an Azure function project (TypeScript) in Visual Studio Code and installed the extension.
When I try to debug or publish it to the Azure Function app I get the error "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.2.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. The system cannot find the file specified. ". Please help.

TSConfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "allowJs": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": false
  },
   "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.js"],
}
```

Launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Attach to Node Functions",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 9229,
            "preLaunchTask": "func: host start"
        }
    ]
}
```

Package.josn:

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/src/functions/*.js",
  "files": [
    "dist/",
    "src/image-target"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "watch": "tsc -w",
    "clean": "rimraf dist",
    "prestart": "npm run clean && npm run build",
    "start": "func start",
    "test": "echo \"No tests yet...\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@azure/functions": "^4.0.0-alpha.9",
    "@azure/storage-blob": "^12.16.0",
    "@mediapipe/face_mesh": "^0.4.1633559619",
    "@msgpack/msgpack": "^3.0.0-beta2",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs": "^4.11.0",
    "canvas": "^2.11.2",
    "mathjs": "^11.11.0",
    "ml-matrix": "^6.10.4",
    "svd-js": "^1.1.1",
    "tinyqueue": "^2.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "18.x",
    "azure-functions-core-tools": "^4.x",
    "rimraf": "^5.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.0.0"
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you share your code in the question?

Comment: Share your **package.json** file also.

Comment: shared it above.

Comment: Please share your code so that we can easily solve your issue.

Comment: you can get the code at   - I am able to run it and deployed to azure too. But in Azure I get the following error:  Worker was unable to load function AnchorImageFileProcessor: 'Cannot find module '@azure/storage-blob' Require stack: - C:\home\site\wwwroot\dist\AnchorImageFileProcessor\index.js - C:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Functions\4.26.1\workers\node\dist\src\worker-bundle.js - C:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Functions\4.26.1\workers\node\dist\src\nodejsWorker.js'                  Code: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qiEatsaMkYm8GeP0RyHg5LiR130UWg4S/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: I think it is not deployed properly or any file is missing. Check it once and try to redeploy it.

Answer (score 0):

> 'Cannot find module ‘@azure/storage-blob’

Make sure **`'@azure/storage-blob'`** package is installed in your package.json like below:-

```json
{
  "name": "typescriptfunction",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "watch": "tsc -w",
    "clean": "rimraf dist",
    "prestart": "npm run clean && npm run build",
    "start": "func start",
    "test": "echo \"No tests yet...\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@azure/storage-blob": "^12.15.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@azure/functions": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^16.x",
    "rimraf": "^5.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.0.0"
  }
}
```

If the package is not installed make sure you install it by running the command below:-

```js
npm install @azure/storage-blob
```

[image]

Below is my **index.ts** that **reads my blob file from Storage account**:-

**index.ts:-**

```
import { AzureFunction, Context, HttpRequest } from "@azure/functions";
import { BlobServiceClient } from "@azure/storage-blob";

const httpTrigger: AzureFunction = async function (
  context: Context,
  req: HttpRequest
): Promise<void> {
  context.log("HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

  const connectionString = process.env[
    "AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING"
  ] as string;

  const blobServiceClient =
    BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(connectionString);

  const containerName = "testhubname-applease";
  const blobName = "blob.txt";

  const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);
  const blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient(blobName);

  const downloadBlockBlobResponse = await blobClient.download();
  const downloadedContent = (
    await streamToBuffer(downloadBlockBlobResponse.readableStreamBody)
  ).toString();

  context.res = {
    body: downloadedContent,
  };
};
```

**local.settings.json:-**

```json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=valleystrg129;AccountKey=xxxxStPI60+Q==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node",
    "kamstore_STORAGE": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=valleystrg129;AccountKey=xxxxtPI60+Q==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
    "AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=valleystrg129;AccountKey=xxxxxStPI60+Q==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
    "AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType": "files"
  }
}
```

```
AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING: connection-string
```

**Add the above connection string in your Function app environment variable:-**

[image]

**Output:-**

[image]